# LinearRegression TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

[image: sample.xlsx]

> The above screenshot is refereed to as: sample.xlsx. I've been having trouble getting the beta for each stock using the LinearRegression() function.

> Input:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
mean = df['ChangePercent'].mean()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    symbol = row['stock']
    perc = row['ChangePercent']

    x = np.array(perc).reshape((-1, 1))
    y = np.array(mean)
    model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
    print(model.coef_)
```

> Output:

> Line 16: model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
> "Singleton array %r cannot be considered a valid collection." % x

> TypeError: Singleton array array(3.34) cannot be considered a valid collection.

> How can I make the collection valid so that I can get a beta value(model.coef_) for each stock?

Comment: The error tells you that you are passing an array containing just one element to the model's `.fit()` method. You cannot run a regression model with just one data point.

Answer (score 1):

X and y must have same shape, so you need to reshape both x and y to 1 row and 1 column. In this case it is resumed to the following:

`np.array(mean).reshape(-1,1)` or `np.array(mean).reshape(1,1)`

Given that you are training 5 classifiers, each one with just one value, is not surprising that the 5 models will "learn" that the coefficient of the linear regression is 0 and the intercept is 3.37 (`y`).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "stock": ["ABCD", "XYZ", "JK", "OPQ", "GHI"],
    "ChangePercent": [-1.7, 30, 3.7, -15.3, 0]
    })

mean = df['ChangePercent'].mean()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    symbol = row['stock']
    perc = row['ChangePercent']

    x = np.array(perc).reshape(-1,1)
    y = np.array(mean).reshape(-1,1)
    model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
    print(f"{model.intercept_} + {model.coef_}*{x} = {y}")
```

Which is correct from an algorithmic point of view, but it doesn't make any practical sense given that you're only providing one example to train each model.